docker: failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: failed to do request:
I have a question that has been bothering me for a long time. I want to use Open WebUI. I have already installed Docker and Ollama. However, I encounter problems when running the command.
docker run -d -p 3000:8080 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -v open-webui:/app/backend/data --name open-webui --restart always ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main

My device is Windows 11 Education Edition.
C:\Users\yuche>docker run -d -p 3000:8080 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -v open-webui:/app/backend/data --name open-webui --restart always ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main
Unable to find image 'ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main' locally
main: Pulling from open-webui/open-webui
docker: failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: failed to do request: Get "https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:afe4f6c41e464601de9d05df575bd3fcbc06fa9a23a13f71509115fa2c654299?se=2024-10-19T16%3A20%3A00Z&sig=LTwxeDZ2BtRDGX%2FpivbQg%2FLJWcRtuudEpqlwPe8ftmA%3D&sp=r&spr=https&sr=b&sv=2019-12-12": EOF.
See 'docker run --help'.

my run pic
I can confirm that my internet connection is fine. Besides that, my firewall is also not an issue; in fact, I even disabled the firewall to successfully install Open WebUI, but I still can't install it.
I am trying to create my own private knowledge base using Ollama and Open WebUI. However, I encountered unsolvable issues during the installation of Open WebUI. So I hope that some experts online might see my question and provide me with some answers.
